# Inserting to multiple table with foreign key in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

These is my first time using the laravel framework and so far it is well structure than others i have used. But these have left me struck in an error i have been debugging a while.
I have a Post model that have sub model Post Images and Post Location. I am trying to insert data to the Post Images and then get the id of the save data into the base Model Post so i can make the relationship these are my code
Post Model

```
class Post extends Model {
   protected $table = 'posts';
   public $primaryKey = 'id';
   public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
  public function post_image(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PostImage');
   }
  public function location(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PostLocation');
  }
}
```

Migrated From create post

```
 public function up(){
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_image_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Base model Relationship are

```
class PostImage extends Model{
   protected $table = 'post_images';
   public $primaryKey = 'id';
   public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
 }
}
class PostLocation extends Model{
   protected $table = 'location';
   public $primaryKey = 'id';
   public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
 }
}
```

In the Post Controller store method. I am saving the post image first and then try to reference the inserted table id as the foreign key and error occur after a while i try to different combination it doesnt work. The images are sucecfully save but the reference dosent work

Post controller store code

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
     // Validation work here
    ]);
    // Function to save images work perfectly and return the an array containg image
    $images = $this->uploadAssetImages($request);
    $post= new Post();  
    $image = new PostImage();
    $image->image1 = $images[0];
    $image->image2 = $images[1];
    $image->image3 = $images[2];
    $image->save();//$image->id()
    //I have try these: $image_id = Response::json(array('success' => true, 'last_insert_id' => $image->id), 200);
    $asset->description = $request->input('description');
    $asset->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $asset->post_image()->save($image);// After debuging error is found here
    $asset->save();
```

Hope these can be resolve?

Comment: Why does your `PostLocation::post()` method belong to a location? wouldn't the `Post` itself belong to a location?

Comment: I tried to split Post Location from the Post. The location did not give any issue referencing  the foreign key is the main issue.